# Can't save file to SD Card

Tags: java, android, android-sdcard

After following a few tutorials i've got a code to save an created bitmap into the SD Card. However nothing is being saved or created.

I have a method to check if i can write into the External Storage, and it returns true (files \ folders can be created). However when i try to create something it just won't.

I also tried an method just to write an string to the sd card (simple file), didn't worked as well.

Is there any config i should set on Android Studio to save files on the SD Card ?
Important: Using emulated device, no physical device.
I've saw posts on SO\Google about writing to the SD card. They all look like what i'm already doing.

Any input is highly appreciated
Thanks

android-manifest.xml:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.saveview">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

MainActivity.Java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        final ViewParaSalvar myCustomView = new ViewParaSalvar(this);
        Boolean CanWrite = isStoragePermissionGranted();


        myCustomView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener(){

            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {

                Bitmap BmpFromView = loadBitmapFromView(myCustomView);
                saveImageToExternalStorage(BmpFromView);
            }
        });
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
    private File GetFinalFileName()
    {
        String root = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).toString();
        File myDir = new File(root + "/saved_images");
        //boolean created = myDir.mkdirs();
        //ExibirMensagemAlerta(Boolean.toString(created));
        myDir.mkdirs();
        Random generator = new Random();
        int n = 10000;
        n = generator.nextInt(n);
        String fname = "Image-" + n + ".jpg";
        File file = new File(myDir, fname);

        return file;
    }

    private void saveImageToExternalStorage(Bitmap finalBitmap) {
        try
        {
            File file = GetFinalFileName();
            try {
                FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
               finalBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
          //      ExibirMensagemAlerta(file.toString());
                out.flush();
                out.close();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
    public static Bitmap loadBitmapFromView(View view)
    {
        view.measure(View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getMeasuredWidth(), view.getMeasuredHeight(),
                Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        view.layout(0, 0, view.getWidth(), view.getHeight());
        Log.d("", "combineImages: width: " + view.getWidth());
        Log.d("", "combineImages: height: " + view.getHeight());
        view.draw(canvas);
        return bitmap;
    }
    public void ExibirMensagemAlerta(String msg)
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    public  boolean isStoragePermissionGranted() {
        Boolean finalPerm;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
            if (checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                    == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                //ExibirMensagemAlerta("Permission is granted");
                finalPerm = true;
                return true;
            } else {

              //  ExibirMensagemAlerta("Permission revoked");
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);
                finalPerm = false;
                return false;
            }
        }
        else { //permission is automatically granted on sdk<23 upon installation
            //ExibirMensagemAlerta("Permission is granted");
            finalPerm = true;
            return true;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: `myDir.mkdirs();` Replace by `if ( !myDir.exists())if ( !myDir.mkdirs()){Toast(could..not..create..direcory); return;}`.

Comment: Further: Yout code has nothing to do with a removable micro SD card.